# Java: Can I have a Map that has 3 arraylists as its value?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm not sure how to phrase the question.

Let's say, we have a word.

That word will be the key, this key will have 3 ArrayList. Is this possible? If so how would I go about this?

Key                |Values

1                 -ArrayList1 
                  -ArrayList2
                  -ArrayList3

2                 -ArrayList1 
                  -ArrayList2
                  -ArrayList3

3                 -ArrayList1 
                  -ArrayList2
                  -ArrayList3

4......

Okay, so what I am trying to do is have a word that has similarities with it. The I wanted to separate these to different array list.

Let's say, the key is tree
the list one would be
list 1 tee, tre....
list 2 tred, trid...
list 3 trees, treen...

hopefully this makes sense.
Also, I feel like this is a silly way to do this. Would there be a better way of doing this?

Comment: How about Map<String, List[]>?

Comment: Without context, it does feel extremely silly and I would be hard-pressed to imagine there *isn't* a better way to do this.

Comment: Hard to sya if there is a better way if you don't tell us what you are trying to achieve with this :)

Comment: Can you use list of lists as value `List<List<>>` or DTO contains these lists?

Comment: I would think an Object would be a better solution.  Using data structures as a complex assembly, like this, makes me wonder about a Collection or Map of Objects that had all that data as private members.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a monster like this

```
Map<String,List<List<String>> hugeMap = new HashMap<>();
hugeMap.get("anyKey").get(0)
hugeMap.get("anyKey").get(1)
hugeMap.get("anyKey").get(2)
```

or you could do it a bit better with creating a class which holds three arraylist.

e.g.

```
class MyNewClass{
List<String> list1;
List<String> list2;
List<String> list3;
}
```

Then you Map would look like this

```
Map<String, MyNewClass> stillHugeMap = new HashMap<>();
stillHugeMap.get("anyKey").list1
stillHugeMap.get("anyKey").list2
stillHugeMap.get("anyKey").list3
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But you need a container.

```
Map<String, Set<ArrayList<Object>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
Set<ArrayList<Object>> value1 = new HashSet<>();
value1.add(arrayList1);
value1.add(arrayList2);
myMap.put("1", value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A map can have one value per one key. That means for each key you need a wrapper object that contains those three lists.

But I think you should start by explaining what it is you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<?>[]>` where the array is always the size of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Getter
public class ListHolder<ONE, TWO, THREE> {
    private List<ONE> one = Lists.newArrayList();
    private List<TWO> two = Lists.newArrayList();
    private List<THREE> three = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

And latter `Map<String, ListHolder<String, Integer, Object>> map = Maps.newHashMap();`

```
map.get("key").getOne().add("test");
map.get("key").getTwo().add(3);
```

I use GoogleGuave to decries code size.